# How do I wrangle animals?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any way to round up animals in Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19546/any-way-to-round-up-animals-in-minecraft)

Is nudging the only way to get an animal into my breeding pens, or can I use another, more reliable method?

Comment: I believe the question has been asked before, but just hold wheat in your hands and they will follow you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you hold wheat in your hands, the animals will follow you.
Good grief, nudging them would take forever. :)

You might also be interested in [this thread about separating them](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38671/is-it-possible-to-separate-animals-sheep-cows-chickens-pigs-in-minecraft-o) into pens. Better read it beforehand. ;)

Comment: Is this a recent feature? Freaking awesome, I did not know this.

Comment: It was added at the same time as breeding.

Comment: And that means it was only added in the latest update, 1.0.0. :)